# Oddness starting a post with "Hi-z"

Tags: support

I can't start an answer with "Hi-z" (this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/169579/4245)

I had to stick it in back-ticks to effectively escape it.

Without that the "Hi-z" was changed to just "z".

Is this Stack Exchange thinking I'm being needlessly familiar and chatty?

Comment: While they're at it, they should remove the content-free "So" too many people start their question with.

Comment: You could reword your answer so that it's *doesn't* start with "Hi-z". It might read a little odd, but will avoid the dreaded backtick formatting.

Comment: Ah, yes, the tristate Hello-Z output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes some salutations are blocked automatically at the start of posts, it looks like you've hit one of the rare cases where it's a false positive. You can see the following answer that shows the regular expression used to remove them:

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)