# Why is Hi deleted?

Tags: bug

When I start my [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/496265/200815) with Hi-Z, it is shown in the preview, but after submission, the `Hi-` part is auto-deleted.
Why is that?? Is it to prevent salutions like `Hi there?`

Comment: It looks like to be a false-positive of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oddness starting a post with "Hi-z"](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/oddness-starting-a-post-with-hi-z)

Comment: @PeterJ It does

Comment: Strange, [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497277/chirping-sound-in-power-supply) has "Hi" at the beginning...

Comment: @KingDuken It starts with a picture....

Comment: Why not use high-z, which is more grammatically correct? (and how it was phrased in the original question) That should get past the filter.